# Why is it called Dramatical Murder?

Tags: dramatical-murder

Is there a special reason for this name? I have watched it up to episode 3 but I still don't know why it's called Dramatical Murder.

If it won't spoil anything, please give me an explanation.

Comment: Technically you might want to play the VN. I played it and there are some different routes I have played such as the Koujaku bad ending, otherwise I don't think it was mentioned but that just gives me an excuse to play it again. xD

Comment: Actually, telling you would spoil something big from toward the end of the VN.　Not sure how they'll go about it in the show.

Comment: @アズーサ oh so its based on a visual novel didn't know that so i looked it up and am wondering will the VN be enjoyable for a non yaoi fan.

Comment: @NoLifeKing- I would suggest playing just Ddmd rather than re:connect first since re:connect has got kinda hardcore yaoi and stuff where as just the first one in my opinion just had a lot of action and only like one yaoi scene but it depends on the route chosen I guess. xD

Comment: Aoba dies in almost all the bad endings.
That's why.